# JavaScript RegEx between tags not working using console.log

Tags: javascript, regex, web-inspector

I have this html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function(){
            var text = $('.chapter').html();            

            var str = text.match(/<\/blockquote>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/);

            console.log(str);

        });

    </script>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="chapters">

        <div class="chapter">
            <blockquote>module-data A</blockquote>



            <p>Lorem ipsum dntore laborum! Laboriosam, ipsa!</p>

        </div>

        <div class="chapter">
            <blockquote>module-data B</blockquote>

            <strong>Part 1 – Introduction</strong>
            <ul>
                <li>Can we do something like this?</li>
                <li>Before doig it, we really do need to understand!</li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Part 2 – Java</strong>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

I'm trying to catch anything between the `<blockquote>` opening tag and the `</div>` closing tag so that the first match will be the the first paragraph in my example: 

Lorem ipsum dntore laborum! Laboriosam, ipsa!

I have tested this regular expression:

```
/<\/blockquote>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/
```

in regex101 and it worked, but when I try to log the match using the inspect tool in chrome, I get **null** in the console.

I think that the regular expression I wrote might correct, but I'm not sure why the console.log() returns null...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Off topic, but your tag soup makes me itch. The HTML was written by someone who didn't understand about semantics at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching HTML with a regular expression is a bad idea. Why don't you just select the elements?

```js
$(".chapter").each( function () {
    var bq = $(this).find("blockquote");
    var elemsAfter = bq.nextAll();
    console.log(elemsAfter.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chapters">

  <div class="chapter">
    <blockquote>module-data A</blockquote>



    <p>Lorem ipsum dntore laborum! Laboriosam, ipsa!</p>

  </div>

  <div class="chapter">
    <blockquote>module-data B</blockquote>

    <strong>Part 1 – Introduction</strong>
    <ul>
      <li>Can we do something like this?</li>
      <li>Before doig it, we really do need to understand!</li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Part 2 – Java</strong>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the issue you should have used outer div class instead of inner div.
Try below code.

```
 <script>

        $(function(){
            var text = $('.chapters').html(); 
            console.log(text);

            var str = text.match(/<\/blockquote>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/);

            console.log(str);

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: This is not working... it outputs the first <p> twice, moreover, I didn't ask to have all of the chapters, but one. Thank you though for the try, I got the answer from @epascarello